# Zend Framework - date issue

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, date

I recently moved website to a new host. The server setup is very similar. I used easy apache to duplicate the configuration on the new server.

However, the same zend framework web application that ran just fine on previous server has this date issue on the new server.

Whether using either of these, the date inserted into mysql datetime column is incorrect.

```php
$row->creation_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$row->creation_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', TRUE);
```

The value in the datetime column is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

If I change the datatype in mysql to like varchar, the value is 2012

If I add a line right under the $row calls, mail(), to email me the value of date(), I get the correct time stamp.

If I concat the date() value to another value which is stored in a different column same row, I get 1970-01-01 00:00:01

I'm stumped!

Any suggestions?

EDIT

No changes in code were made between the move from old to new server.

OLD SERVER
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.9, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies

NEW SERVER
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.9, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH

WHM 11.30.5

CENTOS 6.2 x86_64

PHP 5.3.8

MYSQL 5.0.92

Zend Framework const VERSION = '1.9.5';

Issue description in short:
While php date() provides the correct date value, the zend framework changes the value to just year before attempting to insert into a mysql datetime field. I believe something is causing zend to change the date value before the insert, but can't find what.

```
public function addComment(Core_Model_Item_Abstract $resource, Core_Model_Item_Abstract $poster, $body)
{
$table = $this->getCommentTable();
$row = $table->createRow();

if( isset($row->resource_type) )
{
  $row->resource_type = $resource->getType();
}

$row->resource_id = $resource->getIdentity();
$row->poster_type = $poster->getType();
$row->poster_id = $poster->getIdentity();

$row->creation_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // this date() is throughout app
//if I put mail(send me date('Y-m-d H:i:s') I got correct time stamp)
$row->body = $body;
$row->save();

if( isset($resource->comment_count) )
{
  $resource->comment_count++;
  $resource->save();
}

return $row;
}
```

The MYSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
`comment_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`resource_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`poster_type` varchar(24) character set latin1 collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`poster_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`body` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`like_count` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY  (`comment_id`),
KEY `resource_type` (`resource_id`),
KEY `poster_type` (`poster_type`,`poster_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Suggestion: compare the versions of the _framework_ (not given in that whole list). Observation: _"If I change the datatype in mysql to like varchar, the value is 2012"_ makes me think the variable is incorrectly quoted in queries.... Evil...

Comment: are these stored dates you are trying to format or are you looking for the current timestamp?

Comment: @chris: that is NOT the Zend **Framework** version. `Zend Engine != Zend Framework`.

Comment: @Wrikken * Zend Framework version identification const VERSION = '1.9.5';

Comment: @Wrikken Yes. The framework is in a folder in the pubhtml, and part of a web app. The site was moved as entire cpanel account move.

Comment: I tracked so far to: Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php   Around Line 450  protected function _doInsert()... Date value is intact until $this->_refresh(); ... Though still not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue replacing the PHP `date()` function with:

```
new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()');
```

Comment: I wanted to add that after upgrading PHP to 5.3.27 I no longer had issues dates in Zend Framework. So if anyone else has the Zend date problem, look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a 32 bit machine? PHP strtotime doesn't work properly after 2025 in 32 bit machines . Just a thought.

Comment: Still no solution! :( btw its 64bit